# How to use MAX function

Tags: excel, max

I am trying to pull the name of a row (we'll say in the range of A1:A7), based on the highest number in it's adjacent cell (we'll say B1:B7).

```
Row A     5
Row B     7
Row C     1
Row D     3
Row E     0
Row F     0
Row G     2
```

So because the row with the highest number is "Row B" with 7, the desired cell would be filled with "Row B".

I'm sure the MAX function has to be used somehow, I just can't figure out in which way.

Comment: Best to take the first post as answer when two duplicates are made,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
=INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(MAX(B1:B7),B1:B7,0),1)
```

If however there are more that one max value, it will return the first match.

**Edit 1:**

This solution is using Array Formula to return all values with the max value.

First, select `C1:C7` or up until you have data.
Then in formula bar type this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$7,SMALL((IF(B$1:B$7=MAX(B$1:B$7),ROW(B$1:B$7))),ROW()),1),"")
```

Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (important).
Now you can see in `column C` all the values in `Column A` with max value in `Column B`.
Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Maybe this is asking too much, but could it return multiple max values?

Comment: yes but it will be displayed in consecutive rows, not in a single row. see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
=INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(MAX(B1:B7),B1:B7,0),1)
```

Comment: opps, didn't saw you just posted the same solution. :)

Comment: This way the OP can feel more confident in the response!